# javascript not initialising item

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I run my application and a process is executed on a button press:
  - In the process I initialise an item eg. P2_ITEM with the result of the procedure the process is calling. (I tested this and it works perfectly).
  - I then have a javascript to evaluate the result of P2_ITEM
    * P2_ITEM is now blank (Why?) 
When I run my application a 2nd time then everything work 100%.

How can I ensure the it is correct the 1st time?

Comment: your process calls from dynamic action or simple process after Submit ?

Comment: Please post your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Is the page submitted after you press that button? You have to submit your page for the new value of item `P2_ITEM` to be saved into session state.

Check the value of the item when you run your application first time. Most probably somehow before you run the application second time the value is saved into session state and that's why the javascript function can use it second time.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses.htm#HTMDB03007) you can find more info on session state.